# Is there a way to target the opener page of a Chrome desktop notification?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, notifications, rich-notifications

We use Chrome/Firefox Desktop Notifications for a a web app.
The notifications link to records in that web app, but the links are always opened in new browser tabs. 
So after a few desktop notification clicks the app is open in N tabs and the user is confused.
Is there any trick to target the tab, that opened the desktop notification?
Would be o.k. if only possible in Chrome but not in Firefox.

Comment: page-sent notifications used to have a click event, maybe it still works with extension-sent ones.

Comment: Some experiments later...If the notification is opened by a webpage and not a background worker you can simply use: document.location.href = '/fuubaa'. But if the tab is not the active tab you will not see the change.

Comment: set an explicit window name in the application page

`window.name = 'fuubaa';`

set target tab/window with this name, set focus

`notification.onclick = function() {
    var url = 'http://www.fuubaa.com/#/reservations';
    myWindow = window.open(url ,'fuubaa');
    myWindow.focus();
};`